# Scroll to the top of screen after pull to refresh in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a chat app in which I'm showing messages in table view. When I pull to refresh and show more messages at the top I want to remain on the same screen where pull to refresh is triggered i.e. no jumping. Following code doesn't work and it scrolls down.

```
func refresh() {
    currentPage = currentPage + 1

    if currentPage <= totalPages {
        fetchMessaes(page: self.currentPage, completed: {

            self.messageArray.append(contentsOf: self.fetchedMessages!.messages!)

            // Sort message by ID so that latest message appear at the bottom.
            let sortedArray = self.messageArray.sorted(by: {$0.id! < $1.id!})
            self.fetchedMessages = sortedArray

            self.messagesTable.reloadData()

            // Scroll to the last row of recently loaded messages
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                self.messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .top, animated: false)
            }
        })
    }
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please put table view `reloadData()` inside `main queue` and try?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.messagesTable.reloadData()
    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    self.messagesTable.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .top, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: It didn't work exactly as I wanted. I change row to be pageSize-1 which works up to an extent but when subsequent page has just few less than pageSize elements then it jumps to the bottom of table.